# Query which returns results only if all (non-primitive) values from a compared enumerable are contained in the target enumerable

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

We have a collection of entities of type called **Unit**, collection of entities of type **UnitProp** and a collection of entities of type called **Prop** defined like this (simplified):

```
class Unit
{
    int ID;
    ICollection<UnitProp> UnitProps;
}

class UnitProp
{
    int ID;
    int UnitID;
    Unit Unit;
    int PropID;
    Prop Prop;
}

class Prop
{
    int ID;
    string Description; 
}
```

We have a `List` of `Prop`s (called **RequiredProps**) we need to query the collection with. We want to return the collection of `Unit`s which satisfy the condition of having all `Prop`s specified in **RequiredProps**.

I wrote the query like this:

```
var result = ctx.Units
    .Where(x => RequiredProps.AsEnumerable()
        .Except(x.UnitProps.Select(y => y.Prop))
        .Count() == 0)
    .ToList();
```

Of course, this is Linq to Entities so the query will throw an exception:
**Unable to create a constant value of type 'Prop'. Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context.**

I also tried this:

```
var result = ctx.Units
    .Where(x => RequiredProps.Select(y => y.ID)
        .Except(x.UnitProps
            .Select(y => y.Prop)
            .Select(y => y.ID))
        .Count() == 0)
    .ToList();
```

...but it yielded the same exception.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var requiredIds = RequiredProps.Select(y => y.ID);

var result = ctx.Units
                .Where(m => !requiredIds
                    .Except(m.UnitProps.Select(x => x.Prop.ID)))
                    .Any())
                 .ToList();
```

Comment: I couldn't edit the answer because the edit must contain at least 6 chars, instead of `m.UnitProps.Select(y => y.ID)` there should be `m.UnitProps.Select(y => y.PropID)` and thank you for your answer!

Comment: yep, I found this at the same time, it's edited (PropID or Prop.ID, think it's the same).